# JDBC can't connect - SQL

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I'm getting null pointer exception from this code. I have imported jtds-1.3.0.jar in the library. I also set the configuration in SQL server configuration manager to use the port 1433.

**Code**:

```
public class Conexao 
{

  private static String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";//driver
  private static String banco = "gerenciaRH"; //the name
  private static String host = "localhost"; //wheres the database
  private static String str_conexao = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ":1433/" + banco; //string for connection
  private static String usuario = "sa"; //User
  private static String senha = ""; //passw
  private static Connection conexao = null;
  private static Statement state;

  public Statement conectar()
  {
    try 
    {
      if (conexao == null || conexao.isClosed()) 
      {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conexao = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(str_conexao, usuario, senha);
        state = (Statement) conexao.createStatement();

        return state;
      }
      else 
      {
        return state;
      }
    }
   catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
   {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
   }
   catch (SQLException e) 
   {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      System.out.println(state);
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
   }
  }
   public static void fechaConexaoBD () 
  {
      try 
      {
        conexao.close();
      }
      catch (SQLException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
} //close conection
```

**Console**:

java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Btw im new here and in the language.

Comment: post the error from console

Comment: Thank you for reading. There it is the console.

Comment: So, guys, how are u? well, i finally fix my problem. For some reason the default port was 49164, so i just change 1433 for 49164 and it work it. Thank you guys, especially to Hussain Akhtar. See you guys later.